# "Access Denied" while removing S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have created an Amazon S3 bucket with an IAM Role that has full S3 bucket permissions.

When I check the bucket policy it is written that I have these policies:

- list object
- write object
- read bucket permission
- write bucket permission

But when it came to removing an object for this bucket an "Access Denied" error is thrown without any other description.

Comment: So you are missing `Remove Object` permission. Also BucketPermissions != ObjectPermissions

Comment: Share the policy you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete an object in Amazon S3, you require the `s3:DeleteObject` permission.

See: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html)